# App Service Plan - changing Tier and configure autoscale rule, no metrics available?

Tags: azure, autoscaling, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I created an App Service Plan (North Europe) via the Azure portal set to the Free Tier. I then selected Scale Up(App Service Plan) and changed it to Standard Tier. All works fine.

Next I select Scale Out(App Service Plan) and choose Autoscale. When I attempt to configure a rule for Scale based on a metric the dropdown for Metric name just says 'No Metrics' in the configuration blade. So I am unable to configure an auto scale rule.

However if I create an App Service Plan at Standard Tier and then configure the autoscalerule - it works fine. Is this an Azure Portal bug? Or is there some restriction that is applied when changing between Free to Paid App Service Tiers? Even using powershell commands to apply the autoscale rule fails...

Comment: Seems like a glitch on your end. Auto-scale becomes available the moment you scale up to Standard. You just have to enable autoscale (since it's disabled as free tier).

Comment: I can enable autoscale, but I cant set any metrics for the auto scale out after I scale up... thanks for the reply though.